# Ruby on Rails - BigDecimal Calculation Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First off, the column in the database table is a `DECIMAL` with a length of `10,4`.

If I do this on the console or even in the controller, the result is correct:

```
rate = (1 / 0.7126) * 1.0883
```

but if I do this, it doesn't work:

```
rate = (1 / from_rate) * to_rate
```

The result is simply the value of `to_rate`.

`from_rate` and `to_rate` are the results of database queries and the values are correct, if I log the class using `.class` the result is `BigDecimal`, so I have no idea why this calculation doesn't work as intended.

I've tried explicitly converting using `to_d` and `BigDecimal.new` but they don't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Interesting problem... it looks like the integer division method outputs an integer when the argument is BigDecimal?  Works for Float, but not for BigDecimal?  Try this... `rate = (1.0 / from_rate) * to_rate`... it could be the float division method would handle it.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn, I meant to try something like that before posting. It didn't work I'm afraid, same result. The only workaround I can think of is to multiply the rates by 1,000 to make them integers but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: What's the result in the controller if you do `(1 / from_rate)` ?  Is that returning `1` integer?  What happens if you use `from_rate.to_f` or `(0 + from_rate)` ?  I'd like to confirm that the division part is returning 1 and to see if that's relating to the format of `from_rate`

Comment: Hi @SteveTurczyn, sorry for the delay. Indeed `(1 / from_rate)` is `1.0`, so a float rather than an integer. If I divide by `from_rate.to_f` I get `1.4033118158854898 `. `(0 + from_rate)` also returns `1.0`. Weird!

Comment: HI, ok, well if you do `(1.0 / from_rate)` that is automatically calling the float divisor (versus `(1 / from_rate)`... so specifically use "1.0" instead of just "1".   That's another thing you can try.  Alternatively (as you discovered) if you use from_rate.to_f then you get the correct value... the reciprocal of 0.7126 is 1.40... so that would solve your problem.

Personally I'd rather use the "1.0" instead of "1" method if you find that works.

Clearly the integer version of "/" doesn't work as we'd expect... with BigDecimal fields, anyway.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn, if you want to post an answer, I will mark it as accepted. Thanks very much for your help. Interestingly enough, if I do the calculation in a MySQL query, it also works perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you, answer posted!  Yes, I think it's a Ruby issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From evidence, it looks like the integer division instance method (invoked by `/` as in `(1 / from_rate)` returns an integer result when the argument (the divisor)  is BigDecimal, so in this case it's returning the integer value `1`.  This isn't a problem when the argument is a float as in those cases integer division does return a float.

You may be able to circumvent this problem by just using the float divisor... do that by specifying 1.0 (a float) as the dividend.

```
rate = (1.0 / from_rate) * to_rate
```

Or alternatively you can convert the `from_rate` value into a float.

```
rate = (1 / from_rate.to_f) * to_rate
```